# Is there any way to check if an SKSpriteNode has been removed from parent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to check if this SKSpriteNode has been removed from the screen to implement a piece of code if it has but I can't seem to figure it out.

My code;

```
if (player.position.y > self.frame.size.height) {
    NSLog(@"out of frame");
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                         [SKAction waitForDuration:0.5],
                                         [SKAction runBlock:^{

        levelMenu *mainMenu = [[levelMenu alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
        [self.view presentScene:mainMenu transition:[SKTransition fadeWithDuration:0.6]];

    }],
                                         ]]];
}
```

But this isn't working.

**Is there anything I could do to test for when it's been removed from the parent. I.e. something along the lines of "`If (player hasLeftScene)`or`(player hasBeenRemovedFromParent)`" or something?**

I also tried testing for when the player.position.y > 568 (4-inch display) but it didn't work either.

Comment: Leaving the screen (as in: not currently visible) will not remove a node. You can test for "not on screen" by doing a CGRectIntersectsRect test with self.scene.view.frame and player.frame.

Comment: Best way would be to check the parent property like this player.parent. If it is nil player has been removed from parent.

Answer (score 9):

Check for node.parent. It is nil if it has no parent (was removed from one).

```
if (node.parent) {
// node has parent, was not removed
} else {
// node does not have parent, was removed
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: If a node doesn't have parent, it doesn't mean that it was removed

Comment: just what i needed ;) thanks Dvole. Up voted. Well @nicael it worked for me so... it looks like it does work. if your node is an SKTexture called sarasa attached on self. What i did was if self.sarasa.parent != nil { ... do something }